# Dereference of a possibly null reference inside Net6 IF statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Using NET 6 with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in my project definition I have:

```
if (!(await _context?.Applications.AnyAsync())) {

}
```

I get the tip "_context might be null here" and this why I'm using `?` on it.

I am getting a warning:

```
Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

I also tried:

```
if (!(await _context?.Applications.AnyAsync()) ?? false) {

}
```

But that does not compile. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think it's because the possibly non-awaitable null case.

Comment: The real issue here is a context like that doesn't seem like a sensible thing to be null in this situation.  *That it is nullable* here is the real problem with your code, not how to deal with the possibly null value.

Comment: Do the check before you await, and handle what needs to happen if the context *IS* null. i.e `return` or throw null ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (_context != null && !(await _context.Applications.AnyAsync())) {

}
```